# Updating XML File in Java 8

Tags: java, xml, java-8

I'm trying to create a new child node for each node in an XML file, but my code only updates the last node.

my xml is as follows:

```xml
<games>
  <game>
    <name>game1</game>
    <year>2015</year>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game2</game>
    <year>2015</year>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game3</game>
    <year>2015</year>
  </game>
</games>
```

The desired output would be:

```xml
<games>
  <game>
    <name>game1</game>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game2</game>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game3</game>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
</games>
```

These are my methods to add the  element and write the XML file:

```java
public static void parseXML() {
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("game");
    Node testNode = doc.createElement("test");
    //Get each node from nodeList
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        //Get child elements of node and store in nodeCheck ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> nodeCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
            nodeCheck.add(node.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeName());
        }
        //Add test element <test/> if it is not found in nodeCheck ArrayList
        if (!nodeCheck.contains("test")) {
            nodeList.item(i).appendChild(testNode);
            if (nodeList.item(i).getLastChild().getNodeName().equals("test")) {;
                System.out.println("node exists!");
            }
        }
    }
    writeXmlFile();
}

public static void writeXmlFile() {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                baseDIR.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "testXML.xml"));
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(outStream));
    } catch (TransformerException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is something weird going on as the System.out statement is displayed three times confirming that the child node was added to the nodelist, but in the xml file, only the last node has the `</test>` child node.

Thanks for reading, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only call `createElement` once, so you attach *the same* to three different places *sequentially* (i.e. the second and third call will *move* the element to the new place).

Comment: Thanks Generous Badger, that has fixed it. I moved the createElement statement into the if statement

Comment: It is a task for XSLT.

Comment: You need to close your FileOutputStream as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it via XSLT.

The input XML is not well formed. I had to fix it first.

**Input XML**

```
<games>
    <game>
        <name>game1</name>
        <year>2015</year>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>game2</name>
        <year>2015</year>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>game3</name>
        <year>2015</year>
    </game>
</games>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="game[not(*[local-name()='test'])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <test/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<games>
  <game>
    <name>game1</name>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game2</name>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
  <game>
    <name>game3</name>
    <year>2015</year>
    <test/>
  </game>
</games>
```

**Java**

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.*;

public class Process {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String XSLTFILE = "e:/Temp/Process.xslt";
        String INFILE = "e:/Temp/Input.xml";
        String OUTFILE = "e:/Temp/Output.xml";

        try {
            // I/O
            StreamSource input = new StreamSource(new File(INFILE));
            StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(new File(XSLTFILE));
            StreamResult output = new StreamResult(new File(OUTFILE));

            // Transformation
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
            transformer.transform(input, output);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
            //tce.printStackTrace();
            System.out.printf("TCE: %s%n", tce.toString());
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```